# How to sync two iPhones to the same Mac and to Nike+?

Tags: iphone, data-synchronization, health.app

The two iPhones appears in iTunes but the run data is not synced with Nike+

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Humm, this is weird, mine does ok, but I never tried with both on iTunes... **always one of a time**.

I did found several forum discussions regarding the out of sync with Nike Plus, and this is **from Aug 26th and already have 8 pages** :o

it describes plenty of out of sync workouts (maybe it's an app bug)

http://forums.nike.com/thread.jspa?threadID=28016

probably is a good idea to post on **[Nike forum](http://forums.nike.com/forum.jspa?forumID=20)** as well.